# Spring MVC data binding to immutable objects

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there any way to bind Spring request parameters to an immutable object? Normally, they are bound using setters, which makes the object mutable. Is there a way to force Spring to use constructor or builder (as it is possible e.g. in Jackson via `@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyBuilderClass.class`)